# C++ Convert tuple of homogeneous wrapped type to tuple of raw type

Tags: c++, c++17, wrapper, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I'd like to call `std::apply()` to a function; however, I am unable to because the `std::tuple` I use is currently wrapped. For example:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class T>
struct wrapped
{
    wrapped(T t) : t(t) {}

    T t;
};

template <class T, class ... Args>
struct delay_call
{
    T(*callback)(Args...);
    std::tuple<Args...> params;

    delay_call(T(*callback)(Args...), Args ... params) :
        callback(callback), params(params...)
    {}

    T call()
    {
        return std::apply(callback, params);
    }
};

template <class T, class ... Args>
struct delay_call_with_wrap
{
    T(*callback)(Args...);
    std::tuple<wrapped<Args>...> w_params;

    delay_call_with_wrap(T(*callback)(Args...), wrapped<Args> ... w_params) :
        callback(callback), w_params(w_params...)
    {}

    T call()
    {
        std::tuple<Args...> params; // = w_params.t
        return std::apply(callback, actual_params);
    }
};

float saxpy(float a, float x, float y)
{
    return a * x + y;
}

int main()
{
    float a = 1, x = 2, y = 3;
    delay_call delay_saxpy(saxpy, a, x, y);

    wrapped w_a = 1.f, w_x = 2.f, w_y = 3.f;
    delay_call_with_wrap w_delay_saxpy(saxpy, w_a, w_x, w_y);

    float result = delay_saxpy.call();

    float w_result = w_delay_saxpy.call();
}
```

the delay_call struct works as expected; however, I am unsure how to go about extracting the actual value of each tuple element and giving that to `std::apply()` to execute.

In short, for `delay_call_with_wrap::call`, how would I convert `std::tuple<wrapped<Args>...>` to a `std::tuple<Args...>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid `std::apply` completely and call the `callback` directly by unpacking the tuple using `std::index_sequence`:

```
template <std::size_t ...I> T call_low(std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    return callback(std::get<I>(w_params).t...);
}

T call()
{
    return call_low(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In short, for `delay_call_with_wrap::call`, how would I convert `std::tuple<wrapped<Args>...>` to a `std::tuple<Args...>`?

It seems to me is better avoid `std::apply()` using the old `std::make_index_sequence`/`std::index_sequence` way (see HolyBlackCat answer).

But, if you really want to use `std::apply()`, you can call it a first time to unwrap the tuple (to get a tuple of unwrapped values) and then call is as usual.

I mean something as

```
T call ()
 {
   auto actual_params = std::apply([](auto ... wt){ return std::make_tuple(wt.t...); },
      w_params);
   return std::apply(callback, actual_params);
}
```

or, in a single call, directly

```
T call()
 {
   return std::apply(callback,
             std::apply([](auto ... wt){ return std::make_tuple(wt.t...); },
                w_params));
 }
```

This solution is reasonable, IMHO, if the `w_param` member is constant so you can calculate the `actual_params` one time for all and make it `static`

Comment: Appreciate the solution with std::apply even though the old solution is more suitable after all. Additionally w_params are not constant for my use case unfortunately, so the actual params of type std::tuple<Args...> cannot be calculated in one go.

Comment: @MichaelChoi - I'm agree: the best solution, IMHO, is the one in HolyBlackCat's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution for use in practice, but here's one using a variadically templated lambda to avoid `index_sequence`:

```
template <class T, class ... Args>
struct delay_call_with_wrap
{
    T(*callback)(Args...);
    std::tuple<wrapped<Args>...> w_params;

    delay_call_with_wrap(T(*callback)(Args...), wrapped<Args> ... w_params) :
        callback(callback), w_params(w_params...)
    {}

    T call()
    {
        auto helper = [this] <class ... Args_> (wrapped<Args_>... args)
        {
            return callback(args.t...);
        };
        return std::apply(helper, w_params);
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Qmm3K_)

The idea is to just provide a function that matches the arguments that `std::apply` yields here - it needs to take `wrapped<Args>...`. From there it's trivial to expand the pack while extracting the wrapped value.

We use a lambda because `std::apply` wants a Callable, so we can't just use another member function. Well, I guess we could [overload `operator()`](https://godbolt.org/z/XZlK0P) for `delay_call_with_wrap`. That would be mildly confusing but at least not limited to C++2a (and [missing compiler support](https://godbolt.org/z/8waQrA)) like templated lambdas.

Comment: I see... I didn't realize lambdas could be templatized in C++17. This solution would be easiest to implement in my opinion.

Comment: @MichaelChoi Oh sorry, I missed the C++17 tag. Templated lambdas only exist in C++20 (and, as shown, don't have good compiler support at all yet). But if they were a stable part of the language this would be a great use case.